# Is it possible to bake SSS material as a texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, texture-baking, subsurface-scattering

I understand that SSS material changes depending on the viewing angle. But is it possible to bake it or recreate a similar effect that will not depend on a viewing angle, and bake it as a texture?

Below are screenshots of my unsuccessful attempt to bake SSS I cycles.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @vklidu There is no such option there

Comment: Sorry, I'm on old machine with 2.82 now so you are saying no more feature in newer blender?

Comment: @vklidu No I don't see it in 2.93.1. I will try to use 2.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles > Bake > Bake Type - Subsurface ???

[image]

Blender 2.82 ... so it should be in never as well?
But when I checked manuall it wasnt listed ...

Comment: No such option in 2.93.1 I'll try to use 2.82, thank you!

Comment: yes in 2.82 it works, thank you! I don't see this option in 2.93.1